# IAM Role not working with Docker container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, amazon-iam

I am running a 3 container docker-compose app on an EC2 instance, 2 of my containers are backend written in .NET, and one is a frontend react app. Although my .NET docker images are identical excluding the app code, one of the containers can assume the role from the EC2 instance, while the other cannot. if I try get-caller-identity on all 3 containers, it works on the other 2 containers without configuring any aws credentials/region etc.

on the malfunctioning container, however, I receive the following.

```
$:aws sts get-caller-identity
  An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the GetCallerIdentity operation:
```

I don't understand how on all of my other containers the credentials work, except on this one? I have tried rebuilding the image to no avail. My AWS role provides FullAdmin access, so it can't be an insufficient rights issue.

My Dockerfile look like this for both .NET images;

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["app/files", "app/files/]
RUN dotnet restore "app/files"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/app/files"
RUN dotnet tool restore
RUN dotnet ef database update
RUN dotnet build "app/files" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "app/files" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app.dll"]
```

Comment: All 3 containers are running on the same ec2 instance?

Comment: docker image **mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0** don't have the aws sdk client by default. How does your command **aws sts get-caller-identity** works?

Comment: @Paolo Yes all 3 containers are on the same ec2 instance.  I installed aws cli manually to attempt from cli, but the application code has the sdk to make aws calls within the app

Answer (score 0):

the AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_ID and AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID env variables were set in my docker compose for the non-functioning container, hence the malfunction